# IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I have the following code

```
  @Override
  public void updateSubFragments() {
    Fragment myFragment1 = getFragment1();
    Fragment myFragment2 = getFragment2();

    if (isTrue) {
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(myFragment2).show(myFragment1).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    } else {
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(myFragment1).show(myFragment2).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
  }


 private MyFragment getFragment1() {
    MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentByTag(MY_FRAGMENT);
    if (myFragment == null) {
        myFragment = new MyFragment();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .add(R.id.myFragment, myFragment, MY_FRAGMENT).commit();
    }
    return myFragment;
  }
```

and get this Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1333)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
```

I thought the cause could be that the Fragment has a reference to the destroyed Activity, however, the Fragment was just created, since it was null before. Any ideas why this Exception could be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Show us more of your code. Especially where and how you are calling the snippet above.

Comment: put some check before these lines like this
if(getActivity()!=null){
// above code here
}

Comment: @KhizarHayat that's a terrible solution

Comment: @KhizarHayat Because by doing this you are working around the symptom of a deep seated problem without fixing the actual problem. And the actual problem here seems to be that the op doesn't follow the Activity lifecycle properly,  but we won't know that for sure until we see some more code.

Comment: I added some more code.